# Set Cookie for specific sub-domain from parent domain

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set a cookie for a specific sub-domain from parent domain?

Here in my case, I want to set a cookie for subdomain *abc.example.com* from *example.com*.

**Is this possible?**

> note:- I am not looking for a wild card cookie which is accessible by
>   all subdomains. It should not be accessible to another subdomain.